# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a contact managers program in a console application using a list to store and display the data. I need to view a report that displays a summary of contacts available and then have a menu to allow the user to interact with the program. I have a method to create a contact and a contact object. I also have a method to update a contact but I want to have the user to be able to pick a contact first name, last name, email address, phone number, type and be able to update with the information the user entered. However on this line  Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Contact:{1}" , contactList); I keep getting the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred,
>   Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or
>   equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {         
        //Declare the list

        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

        //Main Driver
        char menuItem;
         Console.WriteLine("Contact List\n");
        menuItem = GetMenuItem();
        while (menuItem != 'Q')
        {

            ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, contactList);
            menuItem = GetMenuItem();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    //Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
    static char GetMenuItem()
    {
        char menuItem;
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nPlease pick an item: "));
        while (menuItem != 'C'
            && menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'Q' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem != 'D' && menuItem != 'S' && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'F' && menuItem != 'P' && menuItem != 'T')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
            DisplayMenu();
            menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nEnter option or M for menu:"));
        }
        return menuItem;
    }

    static void DisplayMenu()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("C-> Create Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("R-> Remove Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("U-> Update Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("D -> Load data from file");
       Console.WriteLine("S-> Save data to file");
       Console.WriteLine("L-> View sorted by last name");
       Console.WriteLine("F-> View sorted by first name");
       Console.WriteLine("P-> View by partial name search");
       Console.WriteLine("T-> View by contact type");
       Console.WriteLine("Q-> Quit");
    }

    //Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
    static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, List<Contact> contactList)
    {
        switch (menuItem)
        {
            case 'C':
                createContact();
                break;
            case 'R':
                Console.WriteLine("enter the contact name To delete");
                removeContact(contactList, Console.Read().ToString() );
                    break;
            case 'U':
                updateContact(contactList);
                break;
            case 'D':
                LoadFromFile();
                break;
            case 'S':
                saveToFile();
                break;

            case 'L':
                sortByLastName(contactList);
                break;
            case 'F':
                sortByFirstName(contactList);
                   break;
            case 'P':
                   DisplayList(contactList);
                   break;
            case 'T':
                   sortByContactType();
                   break;
            case 'Q':

                   break;

        }                   
    }
// allows the user to update a contact
     public static void updateContact(List<Contact> contactList)
    {
        char answer, answer2, answer3, answer4,asnwer5;
        String newFirstName = " ";
        String newLastName = " ";
        String newPhoneNumber = " ";
        String newEmailAddress = " ";
        //Type newContactType = Contact.ContactTypes;


         Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Contact:{1}" , contactList); 


        foreach (Contact obj in contactList)
        {

                answer = IOConsole.GetChar("\nEdit FirstName?: Y/N: ");


                if (answer.Equals('Y') || answer.Equals('y'))
                {
                    newFirstName = IOConsole.Getstring("\nUpdate Contact: please enter the contact's new first name: ");
                    obj.GetFirstName = newFirstName;
                    break;
                }

                else if (answer.Equals('N') || answer.Equals('n'))
                {

                }


                    answer2 = IOConsole.GetChar("\nEdit LastName?: Y/N: ");


                    if (answer2.Equals('Y') || answer.Equals('y'))
                    {
                        newLastName = IOConsole.Getstring("\nUpdate Contact: please enter the contact's new last name: ");
                        obj.GetFirstName = newLastName;
                        break;
                    }

                    else if (answer2.Equals('N') || answer.Equals('n'))
                    {



                    }


                    answer2 = IOConsole.GetChar("\nEdit EmailAddress?: Y/N: ");


                    if (answer2.Equals('Y') || answer.Equals('y'))
                    {
                        newEmailAddress = IOConsole.Getstring("\nUpdate Player: please enter the contact's new emailaddress) name: ");
                        obj.GetFirstName = newEmailAddress;
                        break;
                    }

                    else if (answer2.Equals('N') || answer.Equals('n'))
                    {



                    }


                    answer3 = IOConsole.GetChar("\nEdit phonenumber?: Y/N: ");


                    if (answer3.Equals('Y') || answer.Equals('y'))
                    {
                        newPhoneNumber = IOConsole.Getstring("\nUpdate Contact: please enter the contact's new phonenumber: ");
                        obj.GetFirstName = newPhoneNumber;
                        break;
                    }

                    else if (answer3.Equals('N') || answer.Equals('n'))
                    {



                    }


                    answer4 = IOConsole.GetChar("\nEdit ContactType?: Y/N: ");


                   /* if (answer4.Equals('Y') || answer.Equals('y'))
                    {
                        newContactType = IOConsole.Getstring("\nUpdate Player: please enter the contact's new type: ");
                        obj.GetFirstName = newContactType;
                        break;
                    }

                    else if (answer4.Equals('N') || answer.Equals('n'))
                    {



                    }*/


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you change this:

`Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Contact:{1}" , contactList);`

To:

`Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Contact:{0}" , contactList);`

What happen is you <s>should</s> must start with `0` when formatting strings, in order given with the argument list.

Comment: Not `should`, but `Must`.